# Are comments removed by the compiler of Objective C iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compiler-construction, comments

I just wondered if comments are included in binaries, or does the compiler know to remove them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objective C, just like plain C, uses the preprocessor to do that kind of stuff. The compiler doesn't even see comments.